# Are there options other than color and opacity for fill in Venn diagrams in R?

Tags: r, venn-diagram

When I create a legend in R-leaflet, I can hijack the `color` attribute to add extra flair besides just actual fill color.  It seems that the color attribute is mostly a css declaration and I can augment that with additional css as long as the syntax works.  For example, I have a map feature that has cross-hatching using the `Hatched.Polygons` package, and I added a `background: repeating-linear-gradient` string into the color field and thus drew a legend box with lines across it to signify those items on the map.

Is it at all possible to something similar with the `VennDiagram` package?  My venn diagram represents things on the map, so it would be helpful visually if I could have the circle for the hatched items to also be hatched.  I tried the same thing with passing additional css into the `fill` vector, but it failed.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

```
library(shiny)
library(VennDiagram)

ui <- fluidPage(
    plotOutput("venn")
)

server <- function(input, output, session ) {
  
    set.seed(20190708)
    genes <- paste("gene",1:1000,sep="")
    x <- list(
      A = sample(genes,300), 
      B = sample(genes,525), 
      C = sample(genes,440)
    )
  
    display_venn <- function( x , .... ) {
      library(VennDiagram)
      grid.newpage()
      venn_object <- venn.diagram(
        x,
        filename=NULL,
        fill = c("red","blue","green") # can I put something other than merely a color here?
      )
      grid.draw(venn_object)
    }
  output$venn <- renderPlot({
    display_venn(x)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I can do this in leaflet:

```
addLegend( 
  colors = c(
    "red",
    "blue",
    "green"
  )
)
```

or I can do:

```
addLegend( 
  colors = c(
    "red",
    "blue",
    "green; background:repeating-linear-gradient(45deg,rgba(255,255,255,0.7),rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 4px,rgba(0,0,0,1) 4px , rgba(0,0,0,1) 5px "
  )
)
```

essentially hijacking the css.  Are there any options to mimicking this in a venn diagram?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example so that we can test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: added an example and some additional detail.